# Is Cumber Golden Great Ape transformation the same kind of Golden Great Ape transformation seen in Dragon Ball GT?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-gt, dragon-ball-heroes

This transformation looks almost orange,

[image: Orange Great Ape]

[image: Another Orange Great Ape]

when the golden great ape from Dragon Ball GT looks duck yellow

[image: Golden Great Ape]

Are they supposed to be the same transformation or they are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Golden Great Ape* transformation is the result of a Saiyan in the Great Ape form turning Super Saiyan. 
By looking at either a full moon or a full planetary body (sunlight reflected from a planet also generates Blutz Waves, as Goku used the "full Earth" to transform) the Saiyan can transform.  *[Source](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Great_Ape)*.

We know Kanba has the ability to turn Super Saiyan and we see him create a moon or some form of a planet in this sky before using this transformation. Hence, it is fair to assume it is the same transformation. I would say there is only an aesthetic change and nothing different between the transformations. Something like SSJ4 Goku and Vegeta.